# Why many words (nouns?) end with つ？

Tags: words, pronunciation

Why many words (nouns?) end with つ？ Some examples include 寝室{しんしつ}、万年筆{まんねんひつ}. Is there some underlying patterns or rules that Japanese language learners should be aware of?

Comment: The words you cite are Sino-Japonic, so (as MickG explains) your question is really, why do so many syllables in Chinese end in /t/?

Comment: Not really, I am a speaker of Chinese, and 筆's pronunciation in Mandarin does not have an element of つ。

Comment: Mandarin is not the only Chinese variety, and at any rate I was referring to Middle Chinese. (For a modern variety of Chinese that preserves /t/ in 筆, see Cantonese.)

Comment: The other part of this story is the epenthetic /i/ and /u/ in Japanese.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can answer for the examples given. We have to go back to their origin as Sino-Japanese terms, and in particular to their Chinese pronunciation. Now I can't actually go back to the Middle Chinese pronunciation the Japanese reading reflects, but [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Baxter-Sagart_Old_Chinese_reconstruction) may.

In any case, if you take the final characters, you can see on [the MDBG Chinese to English Dictionary](http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php) they are pronounced `sat1` and `bat1` respectively in Cantonese. **The `-tsu` is the reflex of the final `-t` of the imported Chinese sound. I think that will cover many of the words you have in mind.**

If this does not convince you because of the different vowel, think of going to [the Tawan Min Nan Common Usage Words' Dictionary](http://twblg.dict.edu.tw/holodict_new/index.htm), being careful to look for the *Chinese traditional form* of the character, as you will not find it if you look for a simplified or Japanese form. There you find the Min Nan pronunciation, which is `pit` for the second example, so the vowel is fixed. Strangely, the first example turns to `sik`.

But the Wiktionary comes in there and reconstructs `syit` for a Middle Chinese pronunciation, with a fanqie (i.e. initial-final-tone explanation) that has 質 as final, read `tsit` in Min. Now a final `-t` gets turned into `-tsu` or `-chi` (`-tu` or `-ti` once, I guess) in Japanese (e.g. `nichi`/`nitsu`, 日, presently read `nyit` in Hakka).

As Wikipedia explains:

> fanqie is the explanation of the pronunciation of a character by giving:
>
> 1. A character with the same initial consonant
> 2. A character with the rest of the syllable (i.e. all other sounds and the tone) identical
> 3. A character marking this is a fanqie.
>
> For example, a modern fanqie for 日 would be 让是切: first character for the r-, second for the -ì, third marking the fanqie style of explanation used.

Expanding any further would have to investigate sound changes in Chinese and Japanese, which I certainly can't do and might bring us off-topic, so I hope this is enough for you. Btw this also answers a question like "why are there many words ending with -pu/-fu/-bu" or "… ending with -ku/-gu", if any such should arise, or at least starts: final stops in Chinese are -t, -p and -k.

Comment: It should be pointed out that some changes have happened since Middle Chinese to confuse things: for instance 法 ends in /t/ in Cantonese but originally had /p/;  and conversely 立 ends in /p/ in Middle Chinese but ends with つ in Japanese.